# passing -1 as file descriptor to mmap

Tags: linux, posix

I did an strace on the "ls" command in FC17 Linux.

Following was the output.

```
execve("/usr/bin/ls", ["ls"], [/* 48 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x27c1000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc765fa6000
...
```

I am not getting the purpose and result of passing -1 as the file descriptor to the mmap call, can some one shed some light on this ?

Answer (score 8):

There are two kinds of mappings (areas of virtual memory mapped to a process): file-backed mappings, and anonymous (non file-backed) mappings. There are two ways to request an anonymous mapping:

- (BSD) Pass `MAP_ANONYMOUS` (formerly `MAP_ANON`) to `mmap()`. There is no associated file, so you should pass -1 as `file` parameter. Some OSes ignore the `file` parameter, others require it to be -1 (BSD IIRC).
- (Sys V) Map `/dev/zero`. In this case, `file` is obviously meaningful.

Answer (score 4):

See `mmap(2)`. This, along with the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag, allocates shared memory. It's an alternative to SysV-style shared memory (`shmctl`).